# Jenkins outOfMemory when try to deploy in archiva

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, archiva

I use Jenkins on my local machine and try deploy my jar in archiva ( on local too). 
After a build succes in  jenkins's log I have a out of memory when jenkins try to deploy jar into archiva :

My Jenkins log output :a

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] multi modum-POM Parent ............................. SUCCESS [  0.381 s]
[INFO] FormationEJB ....................................... SUCCESS [  2.196 s]
[INFO] FormationWeb Maven Webapp .......................... SUCCESS [  0.540 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-05T01:23:27+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/317M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ismael/.jenkins/jobs/ProjetArchivaCI/workspace/FormationWeb/pom.xml to fr.formation.web/FormationWeb/1.0-SNAPSHOT/FormationWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ismael/.jenkins/jobs/ProjetArchivaCI/workspace/FormationWeb/target/FormationWeb.war to fr.formation.web/FormationWeb/1.0-SNAPSHOT/FormationWeb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ismael/.jenkins/jobs/ProjetArchivaCI/workspace/FormationEJB/pom.xml to fr.formation.ejb/FormationEJB/1.0-SNAPSHOT/FormationEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ismael/.jenkins/jobs/ProjetArchivaCI/workspace/FormationEJB/target/FormationEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to fr.formation.ejb/FormationEJB/1.0-SNAPSHOT/FormationEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /Users/ismael/.jenkins/jobs/ProjetArchivaCI/workspace/pom.xml to fr.formation.parent/formation/1.0/formation-1.0.pom
channel stopped
Maven RedeployPublisher use remote  maven settings from : /Users/ismael/apache-mavenJenkins-3.3.9/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Deployment in http://localhost:8081/repository/formationRepo (id=formationRepo,uniqueVersion=true)
Déploiement de l'artefact principal FormationEJB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My Jetty Log:

```
vr. 05, 2016 1:23:53 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
AVERTISSEMENT: /job/ProjetArchivaCI/20/logText/progressiveHtml
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/Users/ismael/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.642.3.jar!/jenkins/model/Jenkins/oops.jelly:30:32: <st:statusCode> PermGen space
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$1.reportException(InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:27)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.reportException(CompressionFilter.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I configure my Archiva and jenkins like official documentation of archiva : 
https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/userguide/using-repository.html
https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/userguide/deploy.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I just deploy Jenkins in Tomcat server. The standalone mode with jetty throw OOM.